# notepad++ regular expression find and replace

Tags: search, replace, notepad++

```
es|Material\,Accesorios y Suministros de Plantas y Animales Vivoshu|Élő növényi és állati eredetű
es|Animales vivoshu|Élő állatok
es|Ganado vacunohu|Haszonállatok
```

I have something like that. How to write "find and replace" to have this output (","hu - before next pipe):

```
es|Material\,Accesorios y Suministros de Plantas y Animales Vivoshu","hu|Élő növényi és állati eredetű
es|Animales vivoshu","hu|Élő állatok
es|Ganado vacunohu","hu|Haszonállatok
```

Answer (score 0):

**Find:**

```
(?<!es)\|
```

**Replace:**

```
","hu|
```

Comment: It's finding only pipes. I can't use it, because in document I have a lot of pipes which I don't want to replace.

Comment: You never gave the logic for when a certain pipe should be replaced.  I have answered as best I could given the information you provided.